# The meaning of "вся" in "я вся целиком за ..."

Tags: значения

> Даже когда вы расходитесь, я **вся** целиком за то, чтобы вы общались друг с другом.

I wonder if "вся", along with "целиком", conveys the idea of "100%"? Is this "вся" an adverb?

Comment: don't think i i've ever heard such expression with **вся**, it's almost identical to the English **i'm all for**, could be regional, the usual form is **целиком и полностью за** or **целиком/полностью за**

Comment: Compare with (quite oldish) parody on cheesy novels:

— А ты побольше выдумывай, — посоветовал Быков.

— Как это?

— А как в романах. «Юная марсианка закрыла глаза и потянулась ко мне полуоткрытыми устами. Я страстно и длинно обнял ее».

— __«Всю»,__ — добавил Юрковский.

Михаил Антонович зарделся.

Answer (score 2):

"Я вся целиком за" or "Я целиком за" is a kind of collocation which means "I am totally agree". "вся" separately just means "whole", e.g. "вся королевская конница", and "целиком" separately means "totally" or "till the end".

Answer (score 2):

I was really surprised reading some of this answers and comments because actually neither this is too rare nor it is a regionalism of any sort. The phrase "весь целиком" (аnd `вся целиком` is the same in feminine) is quite common. "Весь" is used for emphasizing `целиком`, like in phrases (from actual literature):

> Апрельский выпуск "Минервы" разошелся `весь целиком` до десятого числа.

or

> Воскресный день он проводил в полном покое, `весь целиком` уходя в чтение книг и газет и в разговоры с детьми.

What you've encountered is colloquialism, it's because there exist commonly use phrase `согласен целиком [и полностью]` and `весь целиком`. Here are some examples one can google:

> - Так я `весь целиком за`, давай развивать наши отношения, твои родители
>     при чём? ([link](https://zadolba.li/20121227))
> - Согласно молве, народ `весь целиком за` Константина. ([link](https://lubelia.livejournal.com/1112861.html))

With `против`:

> - Даже если б ты был `весь целиком против`, с того что поменяется? ([link](http://www.peredovaya.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?p=369985))
> - Cнял фильм о российской действительности, которая `вся целиком против` человека. ([link](http://perminfo.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/aaab003ed799f70b8dad88e4c0129265.pdf))

Comment: the surprise stems on your part from missing the point, because the comments refer to the phrase **весь целиком за/против**, so you're too welcome to share the experience of hearing it and using

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка valid concern, added some examples with links

Comment: there has been no contest as to the existence of such an expression, but only a suggestion of its regionalism, which still has merit i guess

Comment: @shabunc, there is certain difference between "народ весь целиком за" and "я вся целиком за". Compare: "Весь народ вам внемлет, выходите и произносите речь"- and "Я вся вас слушаю". The first will be just ok, but the second... If you mention your whole self it can't be stylistically neutral. Btw, in your phrase "так я весь целиком за, давай развивать наши отношения, твои родители при чём" it's most likely to be what I say.

Comment: @Elena - I've provided quite different examples, including "ты был весь целиком простив" and I insist it is does not regional term

Comment: @shabunc, it is pretty colloquial there, as well as the whole topic on that link, and the Internet is a location of the 21st century, some forums spread expressions as well as local societies. It's not a literature norm, neither is it stylistically neutral.

Comment: colloquial and dialectal are two different kind of beasts - I've never claimed it's canonical. What I've said it's de-facto used and can be googled. Not the most popular form, true, however existing one.

Comment: @shabunc, we can google anything nowadays. I can say that in my area nobody says that. But the Internet blurs isoglosses badly, you know. I would still rely on the context.

Comment: @Elena - that's just not true - you can not google anything - try to google "я пипечу харахондриков"

Comment: "я пипечу харахондриков" is absolutely googable, just give it some time, you may remind me in a week and we'll see... but i don't think you've succeeded in disproving regionalism of **я вся за** which is still a viable hypothesis

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that it is a kind of some pretty local collocation (maybe, Odessa?) or there is some kind of joke with an erotic implication. But to make it sure we need the context.

A more common and neutral version of this expression would be

> Я полностью за  or  Я целиком за
>
> I am all for it.